# PrimeFaces v2.2.1's Schedule: go to a specific Date

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, schedule

I want to have a feature such that when the user clicks on a Date, the calendar will render the `agendaDay` view of that Date. I tried as following:

```
<p:schedule id="timetable" widgetVar="mySchedule" editable="true"
    allDaySlot="false" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.eventModel}" 
    dateSelectListener="#{mrBean.onDateSelect}" 
    onDateSelectUpdate="timetable" 
    initialDate="#{mrBean.initialDate}"
    view="#{mrBean.view}">
</p:schedule>
```

And this is my ManagedBean:

```
@Named(value = "mrBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
    private ScheduleModel eventModel;
    private String        view;
    private Date          initialDate;

    public MrBean() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    }

    public void onDateSelect(DateSelectEvent selectEvent) {
        view        = "agendaDay";
        initialDate = selectEvent.getDate();
    } 

    // Getters and Setters 
}
```

When I try to click on a Date, the whole calendar disappeared and I saw this string `{"events" : []}` on the browser.

I'd be very grateful if someone could show me where I have done wrong.

Best regards,

James Tran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1949

This sums it up nicely. It is used for the initial load, but beyond that it isn't functional. You can look to 3.0M4 which has a new model (and better model) for the schedule or you can do something sneaky like override the FC Calendar it is built on

http://www.planbox.com/blog/development/coding/full-calendar-jquery-widget-simply-awesome.html

via the "widgetVar" attribute so that when you fire a particular click it switches views. To be honest, that's probably faster as well as it would happen client side and it already has all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one! I was successful only through the attribute `view="agendaDay"` in the schedule Tag, else we will not come to know exactly whether the date given by us has been selected or not.